# Military capacity of Turkey during the Cuban missile crisis (1962)?

Tags: military, turkey, cuba

I am doing a Model United Nations Security Council, as the head of Turkey with the agenda Cuban Missile Crisis; or simply put I am playing the role of Turkey in reshaping world history during the time of the Cuban Missile Crisis.

I need to know about the military prowess of Turkey in regard to the following points:

1. Equipment, weaponry and general.
2. Strength of the standing army.
3. Tanks, Anti-Tanks and other heavy artillery or armed vehicles
4. Air force (carriers, fighters, reconnaissance and such

and other general information that I should know in case I am planning to join a full scale war against another country. I searched a lot on the internet but was unable to find many relevant details or links. Any details and links would be welcome. Thank you so much.

Comment: This would be a great question for a new SE forum called Militaria. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't usually do people's homework assignments. However, I think you are on the wrong track when you ask about tanks and planes. Some things to read about:

- Turkey was (and is) a NATO member. Turkey has an intense rivalry with fellow NATO member Greece.
- There were US missiles in Turkey.
- The US had used air bases in Turkey for [recon flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_activities_in_Turkey#U2_reconnaissance_flights) over Communist countries.
- Turkey controlled the Bosporus Strait, but there were international treaties regarding that control.

So it doesn't really matter how many tanks and how many soldiers there were. Using them against the Soviets would have started WWIII, but then that front would immediately have become a sideshow as the fighting spreads to central Europe.

The key question is how the Turkish player in the simulation stands regarding NATO and US use of Turkish bases.